# How to sort JSON by id's values newest to oldest

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

How to sort JSON by ID's values newest to oldest?

HTML:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "json.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
           var id = field.id;
           var name = field.name;
           var category = field.category;
             $("#show_data").append("<li class='item'>"+"<div>"+ id +"</div>"+  "<p>"+  name +"</p>" +"<p>" +  category +"</p></li>");
        });
    });
});</script><body><ul><div id="show_data"></div><ul>
```

Json.php:

```php
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Mary",
    "category": "eng"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Peter",
    "category": "super"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Ben",
    "category": "math"
}]
```

Results:

```
id:1
name:Mary
category:eng

id:2
name:Peter
category:super

id:3
name:Ben
category:math
```

I want the results to be:

```
id:3
name:Ben
category:math

id:2
name:Peter
category:super
id:1

name:Mary
category:eng

id:3 --> id-->2 id:--1
```

Comment: you can't sort JSON, you'll need to make it a javascript object first - however getJSON does that for you I guess

Comment: do you means to sort in descending order of id?

Comment: Here's some documentation for [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - you'll need to implement the `compareFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the `result` in descending order of `id` before manipulating the dom

```
var sortedResult = result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.id - a.id
})
$.each(sortedResult, function(i, field) {
  // Rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to show up in reverse order, you can just use `$("show_data").prepend(data)`. This will insert the last data to be prepended on the top of the div, and the first on the bottom.